# Custom ListView with edittext that saves the info when switching Activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm working on a game that requires players to keep score after each round. I have a custom Listview already that users can input their names into. What I cannot figure out how to do is to also get an edittext field into that ListView so that the names match up with the same lines as the players points.

I have searched both here on SO and on YouTube for ideas and tutorials but nothing seems to work or make sense.

I also am having an issue with my names saving when I switch activities, which is no good because inputting your name after every round simply wont do.

From what I understand ListViews aren't something simple to work with, but you can't really have an app without them. (Imo)

So this is what I have so far and please pardon me if this doesn't come out how it's supposed to, this is my first time posting here on SO and putting code out there.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addItem"
        android:hint="Type a Players Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Add Player" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newround"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/addItem">
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addItem" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/newround"
        android:text="Next Round"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="OpenHomePage"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />
```

And this is my java class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ScoreBoard extends Activity {

    EditText editText;
    Button addButton;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score_board);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    public void OpenHomePage(View view) {
        Intent homePage = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homePage);
    }
}
```

I know it's not much to work with but any input would be greatly appreciated on either of these two things.

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the listview items array into SharedPreferences, and then in the next activity load it and show it,

---

**SAVE ARRAY**

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
    return editor.commit();  
}
```

---

**LOAD ARRAY**

```
public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    String array[] = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

(credit for the save and load to Sherif elKhatib)